# JSON Data Format At End Point

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Tools: Spring Data JPS, Spring Data Rest, PostgreSQL

After creating a customized UserType of Hibernate, I test the code out with a POST method. For the following data format,

```
{"firstName" : "Joe", "lastName": "Cooper", "address" : '{"street": "Street 1", "city": "My town", "state": "CA", "zip-code": "91210", "country": "US"}'}
```

I get an error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

When I have what the recommended json format

```
{"firstName" : "Joe", "lastName": "Smith", "address" : "{\\"street\\": \\"Street 1\\", \\"city\\": \\"My Town\\", \\"state\\": \\"CA\\", \\"zip-code\\": \\"98003\\", \\"country\\": \\"US\\"}"}
```

I get another error

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
```

What will be the right JSON data type format then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is invalid simply because of how you've quoted the value of address.  If you remove the single quotes, it will correctly formatted JSON with the address field as a data structure itself.

```
{   "firstName": "Joe",
"lastName": "Cooper",
"address": { "street": "Street 1", "city": "My town", "state": "CA", "zip-code": "91210", "country": "US"}
```

}

Alternatively, if that field is really supposed to be a string, you need to use double quotes (as is required by JSON) and then escape every other double quote inside of the string:

```
{   "firstName": "Joe",
"lastName": "Cooper",
"address": "{ \"street\": \"Street 1\", \"city\": \"My town\", \"state\": \"CA\", \"zip-code\": \"91210\", \"country\": \"US\"}"
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your input. Neither work unfortunately. I get the same error for them. This time the errors is on postgresql but not fasterxml.  "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "com" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: com..."

Comment: That error isn't related to the JSON format or string, as the text "com" appears nowhere in this data.

Comment: Thanks again. I am aware it is a problem between the input data and the DB, but not JSON format.